# Access attribute in Laravel Blade using firstWhere

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I currently have this code on my Blade:

```
@if ($employees->count() > 0)
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
        <thead>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <!-- Format of date_of_shift field: format('Y-m-d') -->
        <th>{{ $day1 }}<br />{{ $day1_day }}</th>
        <th>{{ $day2 }}<br />{{ $day2_day }}</th>
        <th>{{ $day3 }}<br />{{ $day3_day }}</th>
        <th>{{ $day4 }}<br />{{ $day4_day }}</th>
        <th>{{ $day5 }}<br />{{ $day5_day }}</th>
        <th>{{ $day6 }}<br />{{ $day6_day }}</th>
        <th>{{ $day7 }}<br />{{ $day7_day }}</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($employees as $employee)
            <tr>
            @if (!$employee->user->last_name)
                <td>{{ $employee->user->first_name }} {{ $employee->user->maiden_name }} </td>
            @else
                <td>{{ $employee->user->last_name }}, {{ $employee->user->first_name }} {{ $employee->user->maiden_name }} </td>
            @endif
                @for ($sched = 0; $sched < 7; $sched++)
                    @if ($employee->schedule->count() > 0)
                    <td>{{ $employee->schedule->firstWhere('date_of_shift', '=', \Carbon\Carbon::today()->addDays($sched)->format('Y-m-d') ) }}</td>
                    @endif
                @endfor
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@elseif ($employees->count() == 0 && $user->is_staff == 'True')
    <p>No employees found. <a href="{{ route('employees.create') }}">Wanna create one now?</a></p>
@elseif ($employees->count() == 0 && $user->is_staff == 'False')
    <p>No employees found.</p>
@endif
```

**Controller**

```
        $from = date('2020-03-16');
        $to = date('2020-03-22');

        $employees = Employee::join('users', 'users.id', 'employees.user_id')->where('employees.is_active', 'True')->orderBy('users.last_name', 'asc')->paginate(6);

        $schedules = Schedule::whereBetween('date_of_shift', [$from, $to])->groupBy('date_of_shift', 'employee_id')->orderBy('date_of_shift', 'asc')->distinct()->get();
```

My td rows outputs something like

```
{"id":1,"user_id":4,"employee_id":4,"time_of_shift":"6:00 AM - 5:00 PM","date_of_shift":"2020-03-20","created_at":"2020-03-17 02:20:12","updated_at":"2020-03-17 02:20:12"}
```

I wanted to get the time_of_shift field and display it on the view. I tried using

```
<td>{{ $employee->schedule->firstWhere('date_of_shift', '=', \Carbon\Carbon::today()->addDays($sched)->format('Y-m-d') )->first()->time_of_shift }}</td>
```

But it just gives me an error. How do I do this? Or is there another way to do this around?

Comment: it looks like your output already contains "time_of_shift" (according to what your post says). Can't you just do $employee->time_of_shift? Or am i mis-reading how your output is?

Comment: @maximus1127 time_of_shift is under my Schedule model, which is a foreign key to my Employee model. I can do the relations easily with Django (Python) but I'm seriously having a hard time with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would do an eager load of:

```
$employees = Employee::with('schedules')->where('employees.is_active', 'True')->orderBy('users.last_name', 'asc')->paginate(6);
```

Then,

```
foreach($employees as $employee){
 $current_schedule = $employee->schedule->latest();
 $employee->time_of_shift = $current_schedule->time_of_shift;
}
```

Now once you're in your view, since you've created a new attribute on each employee collection instance called "time_of_shift", you can just do `$employee->time_of_shift` and you won't have to worry about doing crazy collection filtering within the view itself. Every employee that you loop over will have a native attribute of "time_of_shift" based on the latest schedule associated with them in the database.